# Video Player won't play, only blank screen

Tags: android, video, stream, video-streaming, media-player

Hy, I have the following code for a video player, now i've looked for this error on the internet, and on StackOverflow, and some people said that this error, is because the path is not correct. But I've tried multiple link and none seem to work.
This is my apps activity code:

```
 public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements Callback, OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, OnErrorListener, OnSeekCompleteListener {

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
Button startButton;
Button stopButton;
SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
public String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player_layout);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "pause");
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    startButton.setText("Start");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Start");
                    setVideoPlayback();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Ondestroy");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    Log.d(TAG, "releasemediaplayer");
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.d(TAG, "StartVideoPlayback");
    if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "holder sufrace null");
        setSurfaceHolder();
    }
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        startButton.setText("Pause");
    }

}

private void playVideo(Uri path_to_play) {
    Log.d(TAG, "playvideo");
    if ((path_to_play == null) || path_to_play.equals("")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "pathtoplay is null");
        return;
    }
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, path_to_play);
    try {
        setSurfaceHolder();

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "pathtoplay is " + path_to_play);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path_to_play.toString());
            if ((holder != null) && (holder.getClass() != null) && holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "set holder to mediaplayer");
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            } else {
                setSurfaceHolder();
                Log.d(TAG, "setsurface holder from play video");
            }
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "playvideo exception:" + e);
        }
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "playvideo exception2:" + e);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "playvideo exception3:" + e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "@onSeekComplete");

    try {
        if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            Log.d("error", "@onSeekComplete is valid");
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "@onSeekComplete else");
            setSurfaceHolder();
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            }
        }
        mMediaPlayer.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setSurfaceHolder() {
    Log.d(TAG, "set surface holder");
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mPreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mPreview.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    setDisplayForHolder();
}

public void setDisplayForHolder() {
    Log.d(TAG, "set displat for surface holder");
    if (mPreview == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mpreview null");
        return;
    } else if (mPreview.getHolder() == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mpreview.getholder = null");
        return;
    }
    mPreview.getHolder().setFixedSize(720, 480);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.e(TAG, "MediaPlayer.onError() WHAT: " + what + "EXTRA: " + extra);
    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
        Log.e(TAG, "Media Error, Server Died " + extra);
    } else if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Media Error, Error Unknown " + extra);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onvideoChanged");
    if ((width == 0) || (height == 0)) {
        mp.release();
        setVideoPlayback();
        startVideoPlayback();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onprepared");
    startVideoPlayback();
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surface changed");
    Handler han = new Handler();
    han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVideoPlayback();
        }
    }, 1000);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void setVideoPlayback() {
    Log.d(TAG, "set video playback");
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    String path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4dK9yodrsk";
    Uri url = Uri.parse(path);
    playVideo(url);
    startButton.setText("Pause");
}

}
```

Now Logcat says the following:

```
  06-26 14:31:45.528: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): Start
  06-26 14:31:45.528: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): set video playback
  06-26 14:31:45.528: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): releasemediaplayer
  06-26 14:31:45.528: D/MediaPlayer(15678): release() in
  06-26 14:31:45.538: D/MediaPlayer(15678): release() out
  06-26 14:31:45.538: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): playvideo
  06-26 14:31:45.538: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): releasemediaplayer
  06-26 14:31:45.538: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): set surface holder
  06-26 14:31:45.538: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): set displat for surface holder
  06-26 14:31:45.548: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): surface changed
  06-26 14:31:45.548: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): pathtoplay is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4dK9yodrsk
  06-26 14:31:45.548: I/MediaPlayer(15678): This is not a sprint project
  06-26 14:31:45.548: D/MediaPlayer(15678): [DLNA]AP force disable DLNA: FALSE
  06-26 14:31:45.558: D/MediaPlayer(15678): [DLNA]Force disable DLNA: 
  06-26 14:31:45.568: D/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): set holder to mediaplayer
  06-26 14:31:45.568: D/MediaPlayer(15678): [DLNA]setDisplay
  06-26 14:31:45.568: I/MediaPlayer(15678): setLPAflag() in
  06-26 14:31:45.568: I/MediaPlayer(15678): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
  06-26 14:31:45.568: I/MediaPlayer(15678): setLPAflag() out
  06-26 14:31:46.409: E/MediaPlayer(15678): error (1, -2147483648)
  06-26 14:31:46.409: D/MediaPlayer(15678): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
  06-26 14:31:46.409: E/MediaPlayer(15678): Error (1,-2147483648)
  06-26 14:31:46.419: E/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): MediaPlayer.onError() WHAT: 1EXTRA: -2147483648
  06-26 14:31:46.419: E/VideoPlayerActivity(15678): Media Error, Error Unknown -2147483648

 EDIT: For videos that are not from youtube, it does not crash, with that, error, it just does not show the video.What can be wrong?
```

This is the logcat for non youtube videos:

```
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): Start
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): set video playback
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): releasemediaplayer
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/MediaPlayer(18860): release() in
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/MediaPlayer(18860): release() out
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): playvideo
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): releasemediaplayer
 06-26 14:50:09.536: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): set surface holder
 06-26 14:50:09.546: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): set displat for surface holder
 06-26 14:50:09.556: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): surface changed
 06-26 14:50:09.556: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): pathtoplay is http://new.ineed.com/uploads/video/file/11426/Capture_113_1372246928119.mp4
 06-26 14:50:09.556: I/MediaPlayer(18860): This is not a sprint project
 06-26 14:50:09.556: D/MediaPlayer(18860): [DLNA]AP force disable DLNA: FALSE
 06-26 14:50:09.566: D/MediaPlayer(18860): [DLNA]Force disable DLNA: 
 06-26 14:50:09.576: D/VideoPlayerActivity(18860): set holder to mediaplayer
 06-26 14:50:09.576: D/MediaPlayer(18860): [DLNA]setDisplay
 06-26 14:50:09.576: I/MediaPlayer(18860): setLPAflag() in
 06-26 14:50:09.576: I/MediaPlayer(18860): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
 06-26 14:50:09.576: I/MediaPlayer(18860): setLPAflag() out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Worked, i forgot to put an Progress bar, so in fact it started buffering, but the screen was black, and seeing it does not work, i did not wait for it to buffer